# Read a remote file and use the contents on remote machine itself via Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, remote-access

I have following bash script which logs in to a remote machine and creates a file there but when I try to read that file line by line it gives me no output, although cat  works completely fine.
Following is the sample of what I have been doing:

```
ssh $USER@$HOST bash -c "'

echo "Preparing list of files to be transferred...."

rm -rf /tmp/file_to_read.txt

# Creating a new file in following line

rsync -vunr $DIR $USER@$DESTINATION:$DIR | grep ".zip" > tmp/file_to_read.txt

#Following line gives me correct output

cat /tmp/file_to_read.txt

# But the variable FILENAME in following line has no value 

while read -r FILENAME; do

    echo "Copying $FILENAME" # <-- PROBLEM HERE

done < "/tmp/file_to_read.txt" '"
```

Any suggestions ? Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Output is as follows :

```
line1
line2
line3
Copying
Copying
Copying
```

Expected output is:

```
line1
line2
line3
Copying line1
Copying line2
Copying line3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encountering an issue of variable evaluation in your shell script.

Paying attention the way you quote your command will make the variables evaluated on your local machine or on the remote machine.

For instance, the following makes your **local** shell substitute the variable FILENAME, *before* performing the ssh. Simply call "bash -c ..." to have an understanding of that.

```
ssh $USER@$HOST bash -c "'
# ...
    echo "Copying $FILENAME"
'"
```

There's many solutions for that, either by changing quotation (at the cost of loosing "input" variable substitution of your script), or escaping to prevent substitution by the local shell.

```
ssh $USER@$HOST bash -c "'
# ...
    echo "Copying \$FILENAME"
'"
```

Comment: it works :) Thanks for the efforts..  really appreciate it.. Althought I have few more questions... I am kinda newbie...can please share some more examples on what was happening....

Comment: To see what was happening (ie. performed by the _local_ shell), simply run your script without the call to `ssh $USER@$HOST `, just the `bash -c ...` command.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your last line it seems there are some errors :

```
done < "/tmp/bundles_to_sync.txt" '" echo "Bye from $HOST"
```

replace by :

```
done < "/tmp/bundles_to_sync.txt"
echo "Bye from $HOST"
```

And I think you should remove the '/' before tmp to access the same file as above in your code :

```
done < "tmp/bundles_to_sync.txt"
echo "Bye from $HOST"
```

Comment: The '/' is present everywhere in actual code but got somehow removed in the question above. However I took a careful look once again when you mentioned, but still no luck. Why is the variable FILENAME not having any value?

Comment: what is the output of your program ?

Comment: and what happens if you remove quote symbol next to your done statement ? done < "/tmp/bundles_to_sync.txt" becomes done < /tmp/bundles_to_sync.txt  because it seems like you don't read the good file

Comment: Hi Nico It has the same effect with or without quotes. Anyways thanks for your efforts, I got it working by Stéphane Fillod's answer above just need to verify it. :)